# vba list all active users in a shared workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to try and insert a list of users currently active in my shared workbook:

```
Sub CurUserNames()
    uSize = UBound(ThisWorkbook.UserStatus)
    For i = 1 To uSize
    Range("F2").Value = "Users currently online:" & Chr(10) & ThisWorkbook.UserStatus(i, 1)
    Next
    End Sub
```

I want this to appear as a list, seperated by comma's like so:

```
Users currently online:
James Smith, Adam Black, Marie Rayner
```

Please can someone show me how i can do this?

Edit:

With the code suggested by @Jordan:

```
Sub CurUserNames()

Dim str as String    

str = "Users currently online:" & Chr(10)

For i = 1 To UBound(ThisWorkbook.UserStatus)
     str = str & ThisWorkbook.UserStatus(i, 1) & ", "
Next

Range("F2").Value = Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 2)

End Sub
```

I am calling this code in a workbook open / close event like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call CurUserNames
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Call CurUserNames
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

By saving the workbook each time i was hoping that other users in the shared workbook would also see the cell F2 update in realtime with active users.

This doesn't seem to work. It requires each user to save their session of the workbook before they see the users updated in the cell. Please can someone show me a way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building the string first, then setting the value of the cell after the loop:

```
Sub CurUserNames()

Dim str as String    

str = "Users currently online:" & Chr(10)

For i = 1 To UBound(ThisWorkbook.UserStatus)
     str = str & ThisWorkbook.UserStatus(i, 1) & ", "
Next

Range("F2").Value = Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but this lists each user underneath the other with a line break like below

Comment: users currently online:

Comment: jackie smithers

Comment: laura ashfordse

Comment: I updated it about 5 minutes ago to use comma separation, try the current code

Comment: Thanks this works great. Do you happen to know if there's a way to refresh this cell each time a user opens/closes the shared workbook? I want to create a sort of live update of users in the workbook and for other users all to be able to see who is in the workbook. Currently users can only see this changes if all users hit save. See question edit