# Get current users in Excel shared workbook (co-authoring)

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**

I have a shared workbook on a team's document library site, I would like to know the users that have the Workbook opened in VBA on demand by VBA.

**Problem**

The VBA code that I have found only gets the user that executes it, but I would like to know all the users that have it opened at the time that I call the Sub.

**Code**

Nothing out of the ordinary, just tried it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612730/how-can-i-get-list-of-users-using-specific-shared-workbook).

```
Sub getListUsingUsers()
    Users = ActiveWorkbook.UserStatus
    For i = LBound(Users, 1) To UBound(Users, 1)
    Debug.Print Users(i, 1)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

**Question**

How can I get the list of users that are currently active on the shared workbook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba list all active users in a shared workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874617/vba-list-all-active-users-in-a-shared-workbook)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks but it's exactly the code that I pasted and told does not work

Comment: Fair point.  Just tested it on a workbook that I know someone else is in and it only returned me.